# Filter search on language

Tags: drupal, search

I have a D7 website in 3 languages and a search-function. When a user searches for a term, the results are shown in the 3 languages. How can I set the search-module to show just the results in the active language?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set that in the search module. But you can append " language:en" to the search request URL.

Example:
/search/node/QUERY language:en

will filter your search results by only showing english nodes

Comment: how can i only search for my current language without adding that "langauge:en" at the end?